# Wildcard for file path for adding attachments

Tags: vba, outlook, wildcard

I want to add attachments from a specific folder. I specified the file's path and two keywords which are fixed.

There are more characters to complete the file path after 'filename2' and before 'pmonth' which are not fixed and hence I need to use wildcard (*).

The code gives

> 'Couldn't find file'

I have gone through various threads and tried solutions. None works for what I want.

```vb
For ctr = 2 To lastrow

    filename1 = Cells(ctr, 1).Value
    filename2 = Cells(ctr, 3).Value
    
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(str_template)
    
    path = "C:\Users\nikunj.v.tripathi\Desktop\" & filename1 & "_" & filename2 & " -" & "*" & pmonth & " " & syear & ".xlsx"

    With OutMail
  
        .Attachments.Add path           ' <----- this line gives error

        .To = Cells(ctr, 10).Value
        .cc = Cells(ctr, 11).Value
        .htmlbody = Replace(.htmlbody, "#Month#", smonth)
        .htmlbody = Replace(.htmlbody, "#CLIENT NAME#", Cells(ctr, 1).Value

        .Save
    End With
Next ctr
```

Comment: Use a `Dir`-command and loop over it's result. Attach the files one by one.

Comment: hi @FunThomas, Thanks for replying
i have never worked with Dir before, so do u suggest using Dir when specifying the path or while calling it inside the outmail ? could you give an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Dir function effectively in this case, you'll need the path and the file name as two separate variables. Assuming you add another variable called filename, you could then utilise the following code...

```
...

path = "C:\Users\nikunj.v.tripathi\Desktop\"
filename = filename1 & "_" & filename2 & " -" & "*" & pmonth & " " & syear & ".xlsx"

...

filename = Dir(path & filename) ' Dir returns the filename of the first file matching
                                ' the criteria, or returns an empty string if no match.

Do Until filename = ""
    .Attachments.Add path & filename
    filename = Dir ' Using Dir again returns the next file matching
                   ' the criteria, or returns an empty string if no match.
Loop
```

Comment: hi @Sam , your code works perfectly. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course - `Attachments.Add` adds a single attachment and returns the `Attachment` object. How can it possibly add multiple attachments?

You can use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to loop through all files in a folder and add one attachment at a time. See, for example
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-files-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders/